# Does TDengine network communication use TCP or UDP? Or both?

Tags: tdengine

Does TDengine's network communication use TCP or UDP? Or both? Can I configure it by myself? If I can, which item should I configure in the config filev(taos.cfg)?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called "rpcForceTcp" which will control the network communication, 1 means start while 0 stops.

Answer (score 0):

TDengine use both TCP and UDP for RPC as far as I know. TCP used to transport big chunk of data while UDP used for small packets.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of rpc data is smaller than 15000 bytes, use udp, else use tcp. But if the option of rpcForceTcp is seted to 1, use tcp no matter the length of rcp data.

Answer (score 0):

1. By default, TDengine use both tcp and udp port 6030-6040 for better performance.
2. You can manually disable UTP by setting `rpcForceTcp 1` in `taos.cfg` configration file, which is only recommended in weak network environemnt.
3. Prefer to use the default configurations for local network.